# PowerShell script opens browser by itself

Tags: powershell, browser, powershell-cmdlet

The following code is a powerShell script that sends POST request and gets response and store it to `$response`. When I try to get the form value and try to store it to `$wa` , it automatically opens up the browser.

```
$destination="https://adfs.somedomain.com/adfs/ls/";
$response = '';
$username = 'some username';
$password = 'some password';
$AuthMethod = 'FormsAuthentication';
$postParams = @{
    destination="$destination";
    flags='0';
    forcedownlevel='0';
    trusted='0'
    UserName="$($username)";
    Password="$($password)";
    AuthMethod = "$($AuthMethod)";
    isUtf8='1'
}

$url = "$($destination)?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:federation:cas"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Method POST -body $postParams;
$wa = $response.InputFields.value[0];
```

How do I make the script NOT to open up the browser?

Note: It sends post request which returns a redirection to same uri with get request and respond with some form value which I am trying to store in a variable.

Comment: It opens the browser when executing just those two lines? I tried to replicate really fast doing the following and everything stays contained in my Shell no browser opening. `$response = Invoke-webrequest -uri "http://google.com" -Method GET; $wa = $response.InputFields.value[0];`

Comment: I also cannot replicate, I think you're missing something here.

Comment: Have you tried using the -UseBasicParsing parameter?

Comment: There are three input fields. Without using -UseBasicParsing, I get all three of them but if I use -UseBasicParsing, I only get two of them. One of the input fields is lost!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found out that Powershell uses computer's default browser's parser to parse HTML. That is why it opens up the browser.
Using -UseBasicParsing attribute make use of powershell's HTML parser. And turns out Powershell's parser is not good enough for above case at least!

Comment: I ended up doing manual parsing using String class's indexOf and substring methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing
```

worked for me. Before adding `-UseBasicParsing` the browser was opening on a 404.